# Python returns 5 digit timestamp, what is this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp

I'm a PHP programmer doing a bit of Python (3.4) just because it's way easier to do it in Python.
My script converts a .xlsx file, into many .csv files (one .csv per sheet).

Here is the code:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)

for i in range(0, wb.nsheets):

    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(i)
    sheet_name = sh.name
    sheet_name = sheet_name.replace(" ", "_");
    fp = open(sheet_name+'.csv', 'at', encoding='utf8')
    wr = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for row_num in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(row_num))

    fp.close()
```

Full code here: https://github.com/xtrimsky/xlsx_to_csv

This works well, except that I have a field that is a date, in excel it shows for example: 01/01/2009

But the final csv, contains a number that is 39814. What is this please, what can I do with it ? 01/02/2009 is 39815.

Is it a number I can use to find the unix timestamp ? Or is it an issue and I should change my script ? I would feel safer if it would just return the string "01/01/2009".

Can someone please help me understand what I am dealing with ?

Comment: Python is irrelevant here; that's the internal Excel date representation you're seeing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If 39814 maps to 2009-1-1 and 39815 maps to 2009-1-2, then it looks like the ordinal is counting the number of days since 1899-12-30:

```
In [57]: DT.date(1899,12,30) + DT.timedelta(days=39814)
Out[57]: datetime.date(2009, 1, 1)
```

See [Why 1899-12-30!?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559767/how-to-convert-ms-excel-date-from-float-to-date-format-in-ruby)

To convert the Excel number to a Unix timestamp, you could use the [`timetuple` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple) to convert the `datetime.date` object to a timetuple, and then [time.mktime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) to convert it to a timestamp (seconds since the Epoch):

```
In [80]: import time

In [81]: time.mktime((DT.datetime(1899,12,30) + DT.timedelta(days=39814)).timetuple())
Out[81]: 1230786000.0
```