# Dataset has mix of numbers and date format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset has a combination of date field and numbers present instead of date format. I can fix it in Excel and start working on it in Pandas, but I would like to fix it using Pandas itself, so that I can automate this extraction.

Here is a screenshot of the field.

[image]

I have tried using the `to_datetime` Pandas function, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should rather fix it in excel and have a clean export

Comment: Don't use screenshot to share data, that will allow people to work with and give you a precise solution

Answer (score 0):

The values you have, apart of the dates, are not regular timestamps (number of seconds, miliseconds OR nanoseconds from 01/01/1970) this is why you can't use the to_datetime function on them. Be sure that you insert valid values. I suggest you to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853480/python-returns-5-digit-timestamp-what-is-this) to solve the solution yourself

Comment: The problem is its a mixture of both date time format and those numerical ones. Like  I said before I cant use excel to fix this.

Comment: The problem is that you insert theses numbers with pandas, you need to fix your script or take a look the link I suggested you if it's not your script's bug.