# Ruby gem spreadsheet returning dates as doubles

Tags: ruby, excel, postgresql, rubygems, spreadsheet

I have a method that runs through an excel spreadsheet and puts those values into an array then into PostgreSQL. Everything runs fine but the cell values that hold dates are being returned as doubles. How can I get the date values? Also what if I don't know when a date value will appear in the excel spreadsheet and I want my method to convert the double to date only when it's a date and not just another double.

Comment: If they are Integers and Not Doubles then they are "Dates" if they are Doubles then they are Dates and Times. This is because Excel Stores the DateTimes in Serialized Format which represents `dddd.tttt` where dddd is the number of Days since January 0, 1900 and tttt is the fractional portion of a 24 hour Day. Your Best Bet may be to convert them to Strings in the Excel file and then Parse the String through DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@engineersmnky comment and this post helped me figure it out. [How to convert MS excel date from float to date format in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559767/how-to-convert-ms-excel-date-from-float-to-date-format-in-ruby)

```
require 'date'
require 'active_support/time'
puts (DateTime.new(1899,12,30) + 42153.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
puts (Time.at( (42153 - 25569).days ).utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Either of these solutions work. Basically excel stores dates as doubles and you subtract a set number from the doubles excel gives you and convert it to days.